# Unable to ping default gateway after given proper gateway address in 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I am using ubuntu 22.04 desktop version . After formatted physical server & configure with Ubuntu22.04 desktop then default  Gateway was working for 2hour. After 2hour default gateway is not working . I was configure network with GUI mode.

Which parameter need to checking in configuration file for default gateway ?